# Command (or script) similar to git status to show all local commits since last git svn dcommit?

Tags: git, git-svn

This python script is the best I have come up with so far. I just hacked it together and on a cursory first couple uses, seems to be acting correctly, but I can't help but feel there is an easier way to do this or even something built in (though I have searched and searched).

Thanks for the help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                            
import sys
import subprocess

s = subprocess.Popen("git svn log --show-commit --oneline".split(" "),
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Grab the last svn commit's data                                                                
revision, sha, message = s.stdout.readlines().pop(0).split(" | ")

# Grab display of commits since svn rebase                                                       
s = subprocess.Popen(("git log %s..HEAD --oneline" % sha).split(" "),
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
log = s.stdout.read().strip()

if len(log.splitlines()) > 0:
    print ("%d commits ahead of svn. To push them to svn, use 'git svn dcommit'.\n"
               % len(log.splitlines()))
    print log
else:
    print "No local commits that need 'git svn dcommit'"
sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do a `git branch -a` to list all the remote branches:

```
$ git branch -a
  git-svn
```

For me, only the `git-svn` branch is listed, but you may have different names depending on what options you passed to `git svn clone`. Then, use

```
git log git-svn..
```

(substituting your appropriate name for `git-svn`). The above command (note the two trailing dots `..`) shows all the commits on the *current branch* since the *nearest common ancestor* of the current branch and the `git-svn` branch.

Comment: This command does not work for me, git reports fatal ambiguities. I tried "git log -- git-svn.." and "git log -- git-svn..HEAD" and neither display the proper commits. Neither does switching the order of "--" and "git-svn..".

Comment: @nicholas: that command works for me, I'm not sure what kind of "fatal ambiguities" git might be reporting for you. If you do a `git branch -a`, how many times is `git-svn` listed?

Comment: See my answer to my own question. I don't have a git-svn branch, instead I have a remotes/trunk. Not sure why our setups differ... I used the standard layout when cloning.

Comment: My setup might be different from yours because I specifically cloned *just* the trunk and not any other Subversion branches. In any case, my answer has been updated to apply to any situation.

Answer (score 3):

After playing around with Greg's suggestion, I ended up with this:

```
git log remotes/trunk.. --oneline
```

which I will either alias or wrap in a small script.

The reason why this works and his suggestion didn't is that my remopte svn branch is `remotes/trunk` not `git-svn`. I don't know if this is standard or not, especially since Greg assumed `git-svn`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more info about git-svn remote tracking branch names.

Answer (score 0):

Nice.  Based on the info here, I use:

`git config alias.svn-status \!"git log git-svn.. --oneline |wc|perl -ne 'tr/ //s;s/^ //;(\$commits)=split(/ /,\$_,2);print \"Your branch is ahead of git-svn by \$commits commits\n\"'"`

This assumes the standard `git-svn` default remote repo nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my ~/.gitconfig file:

```
svn-status = !"git log `git svn log --show-commit --oneline --limit=1 | awk '{print $3}'`..HEAD --oneline"
```

which gives handy short messages if there are any changes that need dcommit, and shows nothing if you're up to date (assuming you've done a rebase or fetch).  you could modify the params to the outer git-log if you like too.

Comment: Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2097935/2596664 is simpler and does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

One of (they are synonyms):

```
git svn dcommit --dry-run
git svn dcommit -n
```