# View a git diff-tree in a reasonable format

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm about to do a git svn dcommit to our svn repo -- and as is recommended in a number of places, I wanted to figure out exactly what I was going to be committing with a dry run. As such I ran:

```
git svn dcommit -n
```

This produced output:

```
Committing to http://somerepo/svn/branches/somebranch
diff-tree 1b937dacb302908602caedf1798171fb1b7afc81~1 1b937dacb302908602caedf1798171fb1b7afc81
```

How do I view this in a format that I can consume as a human? A list of modified files comes to mind. This is probably easy, but running git diff-tree on those hashes gives me a reference to a directory and a some other hashes, as well as some numbers. Not quite sure what to make of it.

Thanks very much,
Josh

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097737/command-or-script-similar-to-git-status-to-show-all-local-commits-since-last-gi help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use diff-tree, use diff:

```
# full diff
git diff 1b937da~1 1b937da

# list of files, with status M/A/D/R/C (modified, added, deleted, renamed, copied)
git diff --name-status 1b937da~1 1b937da
```