# what's pending in git svn?

Tags: git-svn

I'd like to use git rebase -i to squash the commits that I have pending before dcommitting. It's not really obvious to me, however, which commits are hanging out there. Is there a git svn option I'm missing, or some other recipe?

Comment: Could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097737/command-or-script-similar-to-git-status-to-show-all-local-commits-since-last-g help?

Comment: So it does, if one is careful to pick out the answers that aren't tied to an older git-svn branch structure.

Comment: I suspect you mean "squash" rather than "repack". Repacking is a specific thing in Git that relates to how Git stores its data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see which Git commits `git svn dcommit` will push using `git svn dcommit --dry-run`. You could try something like the below to show the logs of all the commits that would be pushed:

```
git show $(git svn dcommit --dry-run | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $3}')
```